# Query regarding card and matrix visuals in power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a query. I have a matrix visual which already has a categorical measure applied to it. Now, I want the row totals for specific columns from the matrix to display as card visual in my power BI. Does anyone know how to do it?

Please Note: The matrix already has filters and also a measure is made to filter the matrix.

I tried to add the applied measure to the card, was  not successful. I tried the SUM and SUMX, it also doesn't work as there is a separate measure that filters only the matrix and I want only the output from that matrix displayed separately.

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.